# Passing Powershell argument to Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 connection

Tags: powershell, ms-access, arguments, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a Powershell script that will be used to add a single table with two fields and add a value to one of those fields within a Access DB. I would like to be able to pass the DB path and value as an argument to the script.

However, I keep getting errors with the DB path. At first I got this error:

`Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'H:\$DB'."
At C:\users\user1\Desktop\Read_PCRes_DB.ps1:8 char:1
+ $conn.Open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=$DB;')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException`

This happened no matter how I entered the argument; with quotes, without, or with a path with no spaces.

So then I disconnected my mapped H:\ drive. Now I get this error:

`Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user."
At C:\users\user1\Desktop\Read_PCRes_DB.ps1:8 char:1
+ $conn.Open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=$Database;' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException`

I feel like this a simple reordering of things or an escape character needed around $database or a delay is needed somewhere.

It works fine if I hard code the path and value. Below is the PowerShell script:

```
param ([string]$Database = "C:\pcres.mdb", [string]$BranchName = 'BLANK')

$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3

$conn=New-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$rs = New-Object -com "ADODB.Recordset"
$conn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='$Database';")

$conn.execute('Create Table Location (ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Branch TEXT)')

$rs.Open("SELECT * FROM Location",$conn,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)

$rs.AddNew()
$rs.Fields.Item("Branch").value = $BranchName
$rs.Update()

$conn.Close
$rs.Close
```

Which is a slightly modified version of this: [Create Blank Access Database Using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277690/create-blank-access-database-using-powershell)

I am primarily running it like this:

`.\Read_PCRes_DB.ps1 -Database C:\Users\user1\desktop\pcres.mdb -BranchName "Main"`

I am testing this using Powershell 5.0 but it will be used with Powershell 2.0 in production. This is driving me crazy and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I rebooted and it worked. How ridiculous... plays automated recording from IT Crowd